# How to make inner nodes horizontal and leafs vertical in a B+-tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to make a B+-tree where the inner nodes are horizontally aligned and the leafs are vertical? The code I currently have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split,rectangle split ignore empty parts,draw]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=45mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=15mm]
\node {10 \nodepart{two} 19} [->]
    child{ node{4 \nodepart{two} 7} 
        child{ node{1 \nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{three} 3}}
        child{ node{4 \nodepart{two} 5 \nodepart{three} 6}}
        child{ node{7 \nodepart{two} 8 \nodepart{three} 9}}}
    child{ node {13 \nodepart{two} 16}
        child{ node{10 \nodepart{two} 11 \nodepart{three} 12}}
        child{ node{13 \nodepart{two} 14 \nodepart{three} 15}}
        child{ node{16 \nodepart{two} 17 \nodepart{three} 18}}}
    child {node {22}
        child{ node{19 \nodepart{two} 20 \nodepart{three} 21}}
        child{ node{22 \nodepart{two} 23 \nodepart{three} 24 \nodepart{four} 25}}}
; \end{tikzpicture} \end{center}\end{document}
```

I've managed in my trials to make the leafs horizontal but that's sadly the opposite of what I want =(

Comment: Please add the necessary packages/libraries in your preamble to make your code compilable.

Comment: I think that solved it, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** It seem that guessing, what you like to achieve, is on the end :-). See, if this what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts = 3,
                     draw, anchor=north},
      HMPN/.style = {rectangle split horizontal,%HMPN: horizontal multi part node :-)
                     rectangle split parts = 2,
                     draw, anchor=north},
edge from parent fork down,                
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=55mm},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=15mm}
                        ]
\node[HMPN] {10 \nodepart{two} 19} [->]
    child{ node[HMPN]{4 \nodepart{two} 7}
        child{ node{1 \nodepart{two} 2 \nodepart{three} 3}}
        child{ node{4 \nodepart{two} 5 \nodepart{three} 6}}
        child{ node{7 \nodepart{two} 8 \nodepart{three} 9}}}
    child{ node[HMPN] {13 \nodepart{two} 16}
        child{ node{10 \nodepart{two} 11 \nodepart{three} 12}}
        child{ node{13 \nodepart{two} 14 \nodepart{three} 15}}
        child{ node{16 \nodepart{two} 17 \nodepart{three} 18}}}
    child {node[HMPN] {22}
        child{ node{19 \nodepart{two} 20 \nodepart{three} 21}}
        child{ node{22 \nodepart{two} 23 \nodepart{three} 24 \nodepart{four} 25}}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

With above you should get:

[image]

Comment: well, I can't make it generate what I want. I would like the leaves to be vertically aligned but the rest horizontally. I've tried to do that myself but at best nothing happened and at worst it didn't compile.

Comment: No, the image above is not what I'm looking for (that one I can achieve). I would like for the inner nodes (all but the lowest level, where the values are stored) to be horizontal. And for the leaves to be vertical. Which part of my question is unclear? If it is I'd like to know so I can clarify

Comment: that looks better, but I'd like for the nodes with 3 values (the leaves) e.g. [1, 2, 3] to be vertical (like now) but the 'inner nodes' to be horizontally aligned. So the nodes that have 2 values in the example should be horizontally oriented. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: I tried that but being a novice at LaTeX I didn't do so hot, got any pointers?

Comment: see upgrade of mine answer.